# How do you simulate a button press in Javascript, to trigger searching in Simple-Jekyll-Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll

After implementing [Simple-Jekyll-Search](https://github.com/christian-fei/Simple-Jekyll-Search) into my website, I was hoping to be able to populate the search field using jQuery and trigger a search. Unfortunately, it seems to only react on button press.

Can a button-press be simulated to trigger a search?

Comment: you want to get rid of it's current functionality: i.e. searching as you type?

Comment: Ideally not. I'd like to be able to trigger it alternatively by populating the input field with text, using jQuery, and causing a search to occur without the user needing to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then:

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
    $('#search-input').keyup();
});
```

When you click your button, it will trigger the keyup event on your input.

The library you are using is listening to keyup event:

```
  function registerInput(){
    opt.searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
      if( e.target.value.length == 0 ){
        emptyResultsContainer()
        return
      }
      render( searcher.search(store, e.target.value) )
    })
  }
```

Found the code from Github source.

Another way to change the library. Modify src/index.js file like this:

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function(){
    render( searcher.search(store, opt.searchInput.value) );
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, .keyup doesn't seem to trigger a search.

Comment: another way you change the library and register you event there @matchai

Comment: Thanks! :D Worked perfectly.