# Simple-Jekyll-Search will no longer trigger on-click after firing smoothState

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, smoothstate.js

I am currently trying to implement an on-click search event, using [Simple-Jekyll-Search](https://github.com/christian-fei/Simple-Jekyll-Search) on a page with [SmoothState](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js).

After following the suggestion written in this question: [How do you simulate a button press in Javascript, to trigger searching in Simple-Jekyll-Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295302/how-do-you-simulate-a-button-press-in-javascript-to-trigger-searching-in-simple), and adding the following snippet to the library, it appears the onClick event no longer triggers a the search event after SmoothState loads a new page.

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function(){
    render( searcher.search(store, opt.searchInput.value) );
})
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some code to show ? All code in a github ?

Comment: try putting that code into an onAfter() hook in smoothstate. i have a feeling the onclick event is no longer registered after a new page transition.

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the [FAQ](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js#faq) section of the README that might help. Here's the excerpt:

> ***Help! My $(document).ready() plugins work fine when I refresh but
>   break on the second page load.***
>
> smoothState.js provides the onAfter
>   callback function that allows you to re-run your plugins. This can be
>   tricky if you're unfamiliar with how AJAX works.
>
> When you run a plugin on $(document).ready(), it's going to register
>   only on elements that are currently on the page. Since we're injecting
>   new elements every load, we need to run the plugins again, scoping it
>   to just the new stuff.
>
> A good way to do this is to wrap your plugin initializations in a
>   function that we call on both $.fn.ready() and onAfter. You'll want to
>   specify the context each time you initialize the plugins so that you
>   don't double-bind them. This is called a "module execution
>   controller".